# Urllib3 custom SSL key encryption

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib3

In Python's urllib3 under [Client Certificates](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#client-certificates) there is an option for `key_password`.

Currently, I have the key info in plaintext and I want to encrypt it before storing it on the disk.

Here is the implementation:

```py
http = urllib3.PoolManager(
...     cert_file='/path/to/your/client_cert.pem',
...     cert_reqs='CERT_REQUIRED',
...     key_file='/path/to/your/client.key',
...     key_password='keyfile_password')
```

However, I have not been able to find any documentation around what kind of encryption is supported for the key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. I figured it out.

I used AES symmetric encryption to encrypt the key.

Here is the command:

```sh
# openssl rsa -aes256 -in <key-file-in-plaintext> -out <key-file-encrypted>
> openssl rsa -aes256 -in key.pem -out key.pem.encrypted
```

This will ask you to enter a passphrase and it'll create an RSA key for you.

You can use this passphrase and pass it to the `key_password` named parameter.

> Disclaimer: `key_password` is only supported in 1.25 and above versions of urllib3